# North American standard symbol for ferrite bead?

Tags: inductor, symbol, standard, ferrite-bead

Many of the schematics I've seen in reference schematics use an the symbol of an inductor as the symbol for a ferrite bead (makes sense).

But I've also seen other variants of it as well. I don't have the IEEE 315 document, but I know that there are somethings that we do in North America that isn't exactly IEEE standards.

[image]

Bonus question: Is there a document or source that lists North American standard symbols ?

Comment: The great thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from. \[[mandatory xkcd](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png)]

Comment: To make things more confusing, quite a few people draw a ferrite core inductor for a ferrite bead in schematics.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev: Which is perfectly reasonable because a ferrite bead with a wire going through its hole **is** nothing else but a toroidal ferrite core inductor with one turn.

Comment: @Curd  It's partially reasonable to draw a ferrite bead as a inductor, but *not perfectly* reasonable.  At low frequencies, a ferrite bead operates as an inductor.  At high frequencies, however, a ferrite bead operates as a frequency-dependent resistor because its ferrite core is lossy - intentionally.  Here's a good article on the subject: [Ferrite beads demystified](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/50-02/ferrite-beads.html).

Comment: @Nick Alexeev: ...and the same is true (more or less) for any real inductor. I understand, tough, what you are saying: in a ferrite bead it is intentionally, in other inductors it is not.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - totally agree with you.  I got a schematic today with a 1KH inductor on it! Of course it's supposed to be a ferrite bead with a 1K resistance - but it even had the designator 'L' not FB as recommended by IET guidelines

Answer (score 12):

The IEEE is a US-founded organization that has brought "North American standards" to much of the rest of the world. Any non-IEEE symbols being used in North America merely demonstrate our inability to fully standardize those symbols on the continent. [A copy of IEEE 315](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/~spilab/Tips/ansii_graphic_symbols_for_electrical_and_electronics_daigrams_1993.pdf) if anyone is looking.

The alternative to IEEE is the Europe-based IEC, and I could not find any information on their preferred standard for a ferrite bead.

The person who [assembled those images](http://www.nj2x.com/2012/02/what-is-schematic-symbol-for-ferrite.html) had no final answer either; simply put, the IEEE's is the only ferrite bead standard I was able to confirm.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about standards, but here's another option I ran across recently on an Atmel schematic. From the first-angle projection symbol on the schematic and other hints I would guess it to be non-North American in origin, most likely Asian.

[image]

This is another one (European, I think) that I have used:

[image]

IEEE Std 315-1975 has these (both shown in the pirated pdf linked in another answer):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The IEC 60617 symbol for a ferrite bead is shown in IEEE 315A, Clause 6.2.11 as follows:

[image: symbol for ferrite bead]

The class letter to use in a ref des is E.