# Question about symbol in front of MOSFET gate

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

I have a question about a symbol in front of a MOSFET gate.

The circuit that I am analyzing transforms almost ~311 V filtered and rectified DC to 48V DC. In images, I saw a symbol that is in green box. It looks like an inductor but there is no value on the schematic. I don't know what it means.

[image]

[image]

What's with the MOSFET is in this [link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/FCH47N60F/FCH47N60F-ND/1245046).

---

I took a photo of the real circuit.  As [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/506245/313687) says, it is a ferrite bead, yes. You can see it connected to the  MOSFET's gate pin.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a component. Maybe a contactor?

Comment: Maybe a *current source* symbol overlaid on a mosfet symbol? (the 'D' on https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUNxO.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a ferrite bead that goes on the gate terminal to kill RF oscillations.

Comment: But if it is, Must be a name, value or sth.?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood now.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Do you have any supporting references for that? I thought about that, but to be frank, I've never seen this symbol used for a bead. I've found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/243098/19375) and it's similar, but not the same. Also, I wouldn't expect a ferrite bead in this place. The current leakage is specified for 0.1uA, would a ferrite bead make any difference for this? Or is it for the charge/discharge current of gate's internal capacity? EDIT: Ooh, you meant **RF** oscillations..