# Identify SMD component marked LB1704 with a diagonal rectangle on the schematics

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

What is this component marked LB1704 with a diagonal rectangle?

[image: the twisted rectangle]

And what do the marks '1' & '2' refer to? Power direction?

I'm guessing it's some form of fuse or resistor or fused resistor. But before I go removing shields to inspect and meter out the component I'd like to know what I'm even dealing with here if someone can shed some light.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost surely a [ferrite bead](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173656/north-american-standard-symbol-for-ferrite-bead). See the linked SE question for examples of the range of symbols used.

There is no information on the specifications, the "LB1704" is a designator, just as "C1712" does not give you information on the capacitance, dielectric, voltage rating or package size. 1 and 2 appear to refer to pin numbers. In a CAD package all parts will have pin numbers, but often they are suppressed on the schematic, either because the part is symmetrical (like a resistor) or because the same information is carried in the schematic symbol (like a diode) or maybe they use more useful pin names such as E B C. There may be a good reason for the pin numbers (perhaps the part is mechanically asymmetrical) or perhaps the person who created the symbol simply didn't bother hiding them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. You have come up with a response I was expecting and hoping to get. This was my guess after doing research before I found this great place.